# Como fazer um botão no PHP, enviar dados para minha tabela mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu coloquei um botão em minha pagina para enviar os dados cadastrados para uma tabela em mysql.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">CADASTRAR</button>
```

como faço para ao clicar no botão ele faça a operação de cadastrar na tabela, os exemplos que eu encontro é só com o método

```
<input type="submit">Cadastrar
```

eu queria fazer com um botão que eu personalizei, como faço ?

Obrigado

Comment: O botão que personalizou é uma imagem? um elemento html? Coloque tabmbém na questão

Comment: é um elemento html, que usei css, só isso.

Comment: Use type="submit" no seu botão

Comment: sou novo nisso, o button é criado por bootstrap.

Comment: Mas troque `type="button"` por `type="submit"`

Comment: entendi vou fazer teste aqui, obrigado

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">CADASTRAR</button>
```

Por:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">CADASTRAR</button>
```